# Edit Toggle Navigation on Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I have a dropdown box for search and I need to put this on 'navbar-toggle' collapsed like one textbox, not like a dropdown menu. Can i do this? How can I do this?

This is my navigation menu:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top top-nav-edit" role="navigation">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button> 
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home home-edit"></span></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
     <a href="sobre.html">Quem Somos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="representada.html">Representadas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="contato.html">Contato</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" id="search" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-search" style="padding:15px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);">
      <form class="form-inline">
       <label>Pesquise aqui:</label>
       <input type="text" id="search-edit" class="form-control pull-left search-edit" placeholder=""/>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right search-btn-edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </form>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean and I'm sorry if this is wrong but you could also place a search field within the main nav that only shows when the navigation is collapsed using the Bootstrap responsive utilities such as .hidden-lg and/or .hidden-md.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Please take a look at the following:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNjRgp

The classes I'm using to accomplish this are:

```
.hidden-sm 
.hidden-md
.hidden-lg
```

What I added is at lines 21 and 29 of the CodePen in the HTML box.

Comment: i'm sorry for complications.
In col-md or col-lg i have a dropdown box for search. I need to put only the textbox when col-xs or col-sm. Better explained?